# Data structures and search algorithm for multiple predicate

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, language-agnostic

Does anyone know any good data structure and algorithm for searching with multiple predicate.

e.g. suppose I have a set of tcp header data (assuming no duplicate). If I were searching for an tcp header of the list by src ip, I could sort the set by src IP and do binary search.

What kind of data structure/algorithm should I use if I want to find a tcp header from the set that matches all of src/dst ip/port? (besides iterating through all of the set).

Comment: Will you always search by src _and_ dst _and_ port, or will you mix-and-match searches - e.g. some by just src, some by dst ip and port etc.

Comment: @IVlad - I was thinking the same, although Will A's question is important (otherwise you'd need multiple hash tables to account for the different methods of search, although they could all be keyed to one result)

Comment: @IVlad for simple query, a hash table is probably okay. But say if i write a firewall, I want to block all traffic from IP A, B and C going to IP D,E and F on Monday - Friday between 7PM to 7AM and 1PM to 2PM. Also exempt the all blocking traffic on port G. It's easy to write bunch of function to check each condition, but I'm not sure how to put that in a hash.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly the sort of thing database vendors have dealt with for years. If you're going to *consistently* search by src/dst IP/port, you can use that as a criteria for a sort, and look for it more or less directly.

Otherwise, the typical approach is to sort the data by one field, and build indices for the other fields. You can then do a binary search in each index to find the set of records that fits the criteria for that field. The intersection of those sets will be the records you're looking for.

Of course, if you prefer, you can also reduce the number of indices, so (for example) you might use indices to get a set of records with the right source and destination IPs, and then just scan through that (probably fairly small) set to get those with the right port number.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest indexing individually on common fields, then using a merge join strategy to satisfy queries for multiple fields.

You can also use an index for (a, b, c) to query for (a, b) or just (a), so a judicious selection of indexes may allow you to avoid the need to merge join.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could apply [kd-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree) as a means of obtaining efficient multi-key searching?  I can't claim to know much about the specific problem you are trying to solve, but asking about searching in terms of multiple keys, it seems like it could be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ Boost provides something called a multi-index container.  It's essentially a group of hash tables, one for each key, with some code to keep them consistent.